# ASP.NET CORE - Online Shop Order As Guest / Anonymous User

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identity, anonymous-users

I am developing an online store and I want customers to have the opportunity to order without logging in to the system, ie to have the opportunity to order as a Guest or anonymous user. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can set a **cookie** for detection users; for example, for the first, I visit your store, you set a cookie with **GUID** value for me, now when I order something, you use my GUID as an identifier to track my order.

Answer (score -3):

add AllowAnonymous attribute to actions or controllers. Then user don't need to do log in.

```
[

[AllowAnonymous]
   public class Orders: Controller
        {
            [AllowAnonymous]
            public ActionResult PlaceOrder()
            {
            }
    
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't really olve the ops question he/she still needs a way to track the user I believe so that the order can be forfilled.